VBA function to get local adress of shared excelsheet on onedrive
hello i have an excel sheet shared with other colleagues and i want a function to get the local adress of this sheet on their pc when they open it
i have found this function online
'''=============================================================================
''' VBA FileTools
''' ---------------------------------------------
''' https://github.com/cristianbuse/VBA-FileTools
''' --------------------------------------------- 

and i call it by getlocalpath() it works fine on my computer which have the main onedrive but on their computers always doesnt get the shared folder name
for example i shared a folder called x and in it a folder called y that contains the excel file
it gets C:/user/onedrive/y/ but doesnt get the name of the shared folder it self which is of course impractical anyone have a solution or another function that works for what i need ?
thank you all in advance
i tried alot of functions some doesnt work because of registry errors and i can see its a bit too complicated i tryed also the function enivron but also doesnt work when one have more than one onedrive account connected on his pc which is the case

i downloaded it but its only 2 lines Option Explicit

Sorry about that - try this link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q97WIu-59dJfbFPnPIe9tSmtRcg7BlZr/view?usp=sharing
